# Can you explain eval expression in the default .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I was looking inside `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and found this line:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
```

I understand what the test `-x` does, but everything onward with `eval` is not-understandable.

Further more, when I run this line in other Linux distros it will cause an error:

```
#  eval "$(SHELL=/bin/bash lesspipe)"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

This is on Ubuntu 14.04 (bash 4.3.11(1)), and the other bash version I tested is 4.3.39(1).

Can you explain what this line is doing, and why am I getting the above error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the `eval` snippet `eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"`, we need to break it down:

- At first let's check what `SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe` returns:

  ```
  $ SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe
  export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s";
  export LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s";
  ```

  As you can see it returns two commands containing variable declarations preceded by `export` to make them environment variables.
- Now another thing, `$()` is the command substitution syntax that returns exactly what we have seen above i.e. the output of a command, let's check:

  ```
  $ echo "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
  export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s";
  export LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s";
  ```
- Ok, what about `eval` now, so `eval` will just run the two commands returned by command substitution:

  ```
  eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
  ```

  after this the variables `LESSOPEN` and `LESSCLOSE` will be environment variables to the shell on which this command is being run.

Comment: ok, this still does not explain error. Further more, when I do your first step I get  what you say with /bin/sh (dash) but not with bash...

Comment: @Oz123 `lessfile` script comes with `less`..i can not reproduce the error in `dash`, `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh` ..On other systems this can behave differently of course, hard to say without peeking..

Comment: I already figured out that `lesspipe` which comes in less-481, packaged in gentoo is substantially different from the one which comes with Ubuntu (less 458-2). The one from gentoo can be found here https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sys-apps/less/files/lesspipe.sh, and there is even this one https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe/blob/lesspipe/lesspipe.sh. Go figure, I always thought my bashrc is universal. Apparently it isn't...