# Why does "less" accept an empty filename, and show some environment variables?

Tags: command-line, less

I accidentally ran `less` with an empty filename, which I expected to fail, but to my surprise, it printed some environment variables:

```bsh
$ less -XE ""
export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s";
export LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s";
```

*(`-XE` basically makes it behave like `cat`.)*

`cat`, on the other hand, fails:

```bsh
$ cat ""
cat: '': No such file or directory
```

And if you leave out the filename entirely, `less` does error:

```
$ less -XE
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

Why does `less` do this? I can only imagine it being problematic, because if there's some bug in your code that causes an empty filename, you'll get bogus output. (Like, say, `less "$(which nonexistent-script)"`.)

While we're here, why does it print those environment variables? Are they from my environment? They're identical:

```bsh
$ declare -p LESSOPEN LESSCLOSE 
declare -x LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
declare -x LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
```

I checked `man less` but the *filename* parameter doesn't seem to be documented explicitly. Other mentions of it didn't seem to be related to this behaviour. I also checked the [`less` FAQ](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html).

Comment: It looks like executing `lesspipe` with an empty filename is a special usage, intended to be done from a shell setup script in order to set the environment for subsequent `less` invocations. See for example [Can you explain eval expression in the default .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724351/can-you-explain-eval-expression-in-the-default-bashrc). I don't know where this is documented.

Comment: @steeldriver Huh, you're right! I just tried `less --no-lessopen ''` and it failed with `: No such file or directory`. So if I'm understanding correctly, this is a quirk of the Ubuntu setup? (and maybe the upstream Debian setup too?)

Comment: Well, it's a quirk of lesspipe at least, and the lesspipe man page says it was written for Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root problem is that `less` doesn't properly quote the filename it's passing to the `LESSOPEN` command: what it does is ["Insert a backslash before each metacharacter"](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/1d0e8245cd32b149101039adfc0a379daf778de1/filename.c#L138-L143), so that means it doesn't handle null strings at all. You can see it works as expected if you bypass `LESSOPEN`:

```
$ less --no-lessopen ''
: No such file or directory
```

On Ubuntu (plus Debian, I believe), by default, `LESSOPEN` is configured by running `lesspipe` *with no arguments*, which prints the necessary environment variables to set itself as the `LESSOPEN` handler. See [Can you explain eval expression in the default .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/q/724351/301745). So when running `less` with a null argument, the improper quoting deletes the argument being passed to `lesspipe`, and `lesspipe` prints its config.

---

**P.S.**

I considered opening a bug against `less`, but this hasn't been a big problem for me. If anyone wants to take the initiative, by all means, and let me know if you need anything. One possible solution (but not backwards compatible) is that `less` wouldn't try to quote the filename at all, instead the filename would need to be quoted in the config, like `LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe "%s"'`.

It might also be a good idea to open a bug against `lesspipe` to recommend a more verbose configuration usage.